# Drawing a graph on a torus

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

How do I approach this problem?

For a drawing of a graph $G$ on a torus one defines a 'toric dual' $G^{t*}$ of $G$ in the natural way: every face of $G$ corresponds to a vertex of $G^{t*}$ and every edge of $G$ corresponds to an edge of $G^{t*}$. Some graphs (like $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$) have a toric dual but not dual. Explain why is toric dual in general not an abstract dual.

Comment: One should be careful about what what it means to "embed" a graph on the torus. Some graphs can be drawn on the torus so that they don't involve surrounding the hole. There are also interesting questions about what "polytopal" toroidal graphs there are. Graphs which can be realized in three 3-space with flat faces and a single hole (genus 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember that the dual of a graph $G$ only makes sense if $G$ is a *plane* graph (i.e. if you've fixed a particular embedding---if one exists!---of $G$ into the plane). Similarly, the *toric* dual of a graph $G$ only makes sense if $G$ is embedded in a torus.

If you've got a graph $G$ that can be embedded in a torus, does that necessarily mean it can be embedded in the plane? Try looking at your examples of $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$.